# Heroku command return "App not found"

Tags: heroku

I am new to Heroku. I tried to use the command `heroku` to get some inforamtion of my apps.

I can use `heroku list` to get the list. But when I use `heroku info`, it returns

> App not found

What's the problem? How can I fix this error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either run

> heroku info --app *name-of-app*

or run

> heroku info

from the base directory of one of your heroku-hosted applications.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I run both commands in the base directory, but same error pop up.... any idea?

Comment: What does the command 'git remote show heroku' return? does the remote git match that of one fo the apps in the heroku info result?

Comment: oops... i got Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly..... how come?! I don't understand... I can deploy the app to heroku with no problem.....

Comment: have you tried generating a new public key?

Answer (score 1):

there's two sets of credentials in use here. Git uses your SSH key and heroku CLI will use your heroku credentials

From the command line do

```
heroku auth:login
```

and enter your heroku credentials and you should be back up and running

Comment: This worked for me! I don't know why that became an issue all of a sudden. I think they need a better error message.

Comment: Just damn. I spoke too soon. Now `heroku info` works, but `heroku logs -tail` still gives me ` !    App not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "build" and "install" commands in the package.json file on the root directory of your project. If you are using Nodejs:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Comment: It may be valuable to explain why this will solve the problem described in the question.